# Why different values but with the same code

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having problems with my app I try to multiply 2 **UITextField** values to give the result in a **UILabel**. but when I run the application on the simulator the multiplication and the result is ok but when i run in my iDevice the result is different because it does not recognize the "point" of the decimal point used in my country (Brazil) in values (currency) i think.

an image below to see the difference:
[image: an image below to see the difference]
the code I am using is:

```
//create NSNumberFormatter to be able to show currency
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

//Calculate total cost of trip
NSNumber *total = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(([self.quantos.text doubleValue]) * [self.pricePerIten.text doubleValue])];

//Set the total cost label
self.totalCost.text = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:total];
```

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try to use `NSLog()` to see the actual value of `total`? It looks like the text in your labels is formatted to different currencies? (US dollar vs. Brazilian Real?)

Comment: Also, the "." vs. "," as a decimal point marker suggests a difference in locale between Xcode and the device. It would be nice if someone versed in number formatting and iOS locales could add some details... (I never quite got it thoroughly)

Comment: Hello @NicolasMiari am new to the sdk. but i think that the problem is in the locale. I'm about to give up. the only thing I wanted was to multiply the number * value to know the total bill you understand?

Comment: Yes. As I said, I'm not so versed in locales and number formatting, but if you converted the strings to CGFloats (with -[NSString floatValue]) and add, you should get the same value. Of course, when dealing with sums of money, NSDecimalNumber saves you errors from coverting from binary, I think... Just some pointers, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [self.quantos.text doubleValue], try using [[numberFormatter numberWithString:self.quantos.text] doubleValue].

Same for pricePerIten.

EDIT:

Here's some sample code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

NSLog(@"Locale: %@", numberFormatter.locale.localeIdentifier);

// I don't know how you are constructing the text that you display
// in the text fields, so these two lines are just for testing purposes
NSString *quantityString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(2.50)];
NSString *priceString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(3)];

NSLog(@"Quantity string: %@", quantityString);
NSLog(@"Price string: %@", priceString);

// Use your formatter to convert the input strings to
// an NSNumber and then double
double quantity = [[numberFormatter numberFromString:quantityString] doubleValue];
double price = [[numberFormatter numberFromString:priceString] doubleValue];

double total = quantity * price;

NSLog(@"Quantity double: %f", quantity);
NSLog(@"Price double: %f", price);
NSLog(@"Total double: %f", total);

// Now convert the total back to an NSNumber...
NSNumber *totalNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:total];

// ...and then to a string for display
NSString *totalString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:totalNumber];

NSLog(@"Total string: %@", totalString);
```

Comment: then the code would look like this:
    NSNumber *total = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(([[numberFormatter numberWithString:self.quantos.text] doubleValue]) * [[numberFormatter numberWithString:self.pricePerIten.text] doubleValue]))];    
???